# Dynamic Image Sizing

Tags: html, css

I'm working on creating a set of images that spans the width of the page on my website. Normally this would be fine, however, as I am allowing the page to dynamically resize, my images stretch (or compress) and get a little bit distorted.

Does anyone know of a way to essentially, just create windows for the images that resize, while the images sit statically underneath?

If you want an example of my issue you can go [here](http://www.aprohlimage.com).

Comment: try setting your images, that I assume are in a wrapper, to img { display: block; width: 15%; height: auto; } as a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

I would just resize your images with a batch resize program. Any dynamic resizing is going to make speed or image quality suffer. If you download, resize once, upload, you will never have to worry about that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: if you can easily download all the image files, you can use a program to resize all of them with appended file names as in {file-name}-{pixel-size}.{file-extension}. My coworker does this for me so I don't know the program he uses but will find out now if I can.

Comment: Which would require . . . lots. of copies of the same image right? That would essentially require 1 photo for every 5 - 10 pixel difference in size.

Comment: How many sizes do you need? Unless harddrive space is an issue you might as well upload a file for each size I think. We have 5 sizes for each image. If we have a folder of every image in the maximum pixel size we can easily make photos of any pixel size and append -{pixel size} to the file name.

Comment: The program is called XnConvert and it runs on mac, win or linux

Comment: I guess I am overlooking the "dynamic resizing" thing, but this is the best way to offer multiple, pre-defined image sizes... if you really feel the need to dynamically resize to any pixel width you will have to sacrifice image quality.

Comment: As far as load-time would go on the users end that is definitely not a feasible solution. I can understand having three or four ( a thumbnail, a regular, a large, and a download ) but more than that and you are getting into risky territory. I am looking for more of a window resizing solution than an image resizing solution. Thanks Though.

Comment: Conditional loading is great, but in this case, I think it's a little overkill. They just need an auto height basically.

Comment: I was never suggesting that you make an image for every single pixel size to switch between. I can see few good reason to offer completely dynamic image resizing. Just decide what the largest practical image size is and show it in that size... resizing images in a browser is not wise, period. It will distort your images and increase load time on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It's hard to tell what you want to happen... I mean, on small screens it's not going to be super cool. I would suggest getting some media queries involved, but this should show you a first step in your approach. http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/NvFwe/  I hope it helps.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img alt="image description" src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
    <img alt="image description" src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
    <img alt="image description" src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
    <img alt="image description" src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
    <img alt="image description" src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #f06;
}

.wrapper img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
```

Comment: I don't actually want the images to resize. Static images ( depending on media query block ) with a wrapper over the top. That has windows through to the images. The windows would then resize.